# Как посмотреть ключевые слова в Google вебмастер?

Tags: seo, google-webmasters

Всё перерыл, так и не понял, где в google вебмастер можно посмотреть ключевые слова который он определил у меня на странице?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно год назад Гугл отключил эту функцию в Поисковой консоле вебмастера. Смотрите статью в **[Официальном блоге вебмастера Гугл Saying goodbye to Content Keywords](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/11/saying-goodbye-to-content-keywords.html)**.